# Split tuple with multiple fields to tuples with single field in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have tuples with varied length. I am trying to convert them to tuples with only one field(each field is a map).
Original data:

```
dump entryArray;
([symbol#HIG,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#743094])
([symbol#PEW,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#743084])
([symbol#AFFY,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#5585],[symbol#RFG,security_type#ETF,foreign_entry_id#5586],[symbol#SCHW,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#5587],[symbol#VWO,security_type#ETF,foreign_entry_id#5588])
```

I hope the output would be(each field still be map):

```
([symbol#HIG,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#743094])
([symbol#PEW,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#743084])
([symbol#AFFY,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#5585])   
([symbol#RFG,security_type#ETF,foreign_entry_id#5586])
([symbol#SCHW,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#5587])
([symbol#VWO,security_type#ETF,foreign_entry_id#5588])
```

I have tried: `entry = FOREACH entryArray GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG());` the output has same format, but it seems that the field is no longer MAP:

```
entry = FOREACH entryArray GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG());
dump entry;
([symbol#HIG,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#743094])
([symbol#PEW,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#743084])
([symbol#AFFY,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#5585])   
([symbol#RFG,security_type#ETF,foreign_entry_id#5586])
([symbol#SCHW,security_type#EQUITY,foreign_entry_id#5587])
([symbol#VWO,security_type#ETF,foreign_entry_id#5588])

security_type = FOREACH entry GENERATE FLATTEN($0#'security_type');
it throws:
ERROR 1052: Cannot cast bytearray to map with schema :map
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.validators.TypeCheckerException: ERROR 1059: <line 18, column 16> Problem while reconciling output schema of ForEach
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.throwTypeCheckerException(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:141)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.visit(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:181)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOForEach.accept(LOForEach.java:75)
......
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the schema for the 'Original data'?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you have to split your tuple with ','. See the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758736/apache-pig-merging-list-of-attributes-into-a-single-tuple

Comment: The schema of Original data is too complicated to provide... I simplified it here

Comment: Because each field is a map, I could not use STRSPLT

Comment: How are you creating the tuple of maps?  If you don't have a set length for the tuple, then you should be using a bag instead (especially since you need to `FLATTEN` it).

Comment: I generate from json map, `entryArray = FOREACH acctDataJsonized GENERATE FLATTEN(acctDataJson#'entries');` acctDataJsonized is JSON data converted to map

Comment: Could you add the output of `DESCRIBE acctDataJsonized ;` and `DESCRIBE entryArray ;` to the question?